# HTML tbody and thead in rotated table

Tags: html, validation, html-table

In HTML we can use `<tbody>` and `<thead>`.

Which works fine with a 'normal' table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1-1</td>
      <td>data1-2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However sometimes there is a rotated table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>col1</th>
    <td>data1-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>col2</th>
    <td>data1-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I use a rotated table I never use `<tbody>` or `<tbody>`.

However if I'm correct the `<tbody>` is mandatory if a `<tfoot>` is used.

[Does a <tr> have to be inside a <tbody>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872924/does-a-tr-have-to-be-inside-a-tbody#answer-5939753)

So my question is:

Is the above statement correct (that it is indeed mandatory if a `<tfoot>` is used)?

If so where would you add `<thead>`s and `<tbody>`s in the second example table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) the `tbody` tag is always mandatory unless your table has only one table body and there is no header and foot sections.

In your case you can use:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>data1-1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>data1-2</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

That is HTML valid. Since you don't have "real" header on top of the table I think no header tag applies here. I'm not sure rotated tables are supported by HTML convention, so you basically have a normal table with only body.

Comment: I do need to use `<th>`s or I need to add extra classes for the 'header' cells (which is a last resort). Will it still validate?

Comment: Yes, you can use th for the 'header' cells, or add class attribute for css styling / javascript. In both cases it validates. You can try yourself with http://validator.w3.org/check