# Appending tr to table appends a new tbody to html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tn4euhsn/8/

HTML:

```
<table id="tab" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>A col1</td>
        <td>A col2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log("Here!");
var table = document.getElementById("tab");
var trnew = document.createElement("tr");
trnew.id = "row" + 2;
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
td1.innerHTML= "r2col1";
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
td2.innerHTML= "r2col2";
trnew.appendChild(td1);
trnew.appendChild(td2);
table.appendChild(trnew);
console.log(table.outerHTML);
```

I am trying to append a new `<tr>` to a table. But instead a `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>`
gets appended, resulting in 2 `<tbody>` elements in html table.

So whats wrong here? and how do I do it? (I don't want to use jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it already has a *default* `tbody` tag so you have to use it instead of introducing new one.

```
var table = document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
```

Also you can simplify it like

```
var table = document.getElementById("tab").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var trnew = document.createElement("tr");
trnew.id = "row" + 2;
for (var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "r2col" + i;
    trnew.appendChild(td);   
}
table.appendChild(trnew);


console.log(table.outerHTML);
```

---

### Update:

While trying to figure out the reason, I came across [**HTMLTableElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow),

> If a table has multiple tbody elements, by default, the new row is
>   inserted into the last `tbody`. To insert the row into a specific `tbody`

Here is an updated version of the above code

```
var table = document.getElementById("tab");
var index = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
var newRow = table.insertRow(index);
newRow.id = "row" + 2;
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);
    var newText = document.createTextNode("r2col" + i);
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

console.log(table);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/tn4euhsn/10/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the browser will give it a tbody by default, try this:

```
<table border=1>
    <tbody id="tab">
        <tr>
            <td>A col1</td>
            <td>A col2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Append to the tbody not to the table.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn4euhsn/9/)

Comment: Pls chk the fiddle yourself bfore posting here!

Comment: @rahulserver I did check your fiddle, and I amended it, did you have a specific issue with my answer?

Comment: i assume you are talking about the link you have mentioned in your answer. On running that fiddle, it does not append a row to the table(which was my original question)

Comment: @rahulserver look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872924/does-a-tr-have-to-be-inside-a-tbody, you can't append a tr to a table, it must belong to a thead, tbody or tfoot and will default to tbody if you don't specify but you can have multiple tbody tags so instead of guessing which one to use it creates a new one.